# Aligning vertices to centre

Tags: modeling

I am new to Blender.

I am making a character using the mirror technique, however there is a hole in his head.

I understand that there is a single vertex that needs to be aligned in the middle to fix it, however if I do it by hand it will not be perfect.

How do I align this vertex so it creates a solid head?

In this case, I imagine it is quite simple as it is perpendicular to the X axis, however if it was not, how would I fix it?

Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get there quite easily using Vertex Snapping.

Enable *Snapping > Vertex*, and use the *Move tool* to align it to other verts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I am now making spiky hair for my character, and would like the spikes to be the same height in relation to the face that they are being extruded off. I would also like each spike to be perpendicular to the face that it is being extruded off. Is there a tool for this? I would have posted another question but there are time limits :/

Comment: isn't the Clipping option what he's looking for?

Comment: I might have worded that wrong. What I mean is that the answer above worked, however if i want to scale an extruded face the same amount how do I do that.

Comment: @Malted_Wheaties Hello :). Please post it as a new question with images and I'm sure someone will help.